# is ping measured in time to and from the server, or time between the request being made and the server receiving it?

Tags: javascript

look at the title

idk how to do specifically, a ping in javascript,

but I made this itty bitty snippet that returns

- the time the request was made,
- the time the server received the request, (done from server side)
- and the time the server sent the response.

```
async function getResponseTimeOnce(){
  var times = {};
  times.beforeRequest = Date.now();
  await fetch("https://randobytes.yimmee.repl.co/ping").then((serverReceive)=>{
    serverReceive.json().then((serverReceive)=>{
      times.serverReceive = serverReceive;
    });
    times.afterRequest = Date.now();
  });
  return times;
}
```

all I'm asking, is, which values am I supposed to subtract to get the ping time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard `ping` programs, the latency measurement is always the round-trip-time (RTT). You should subtract beforeRequest from afterRequest to get the difference.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Round_Trip_Time_(RTT)

```
$ ping example.com
PING example.com (216.58.194.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=25.050 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=23.781 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=24.287 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=34.904 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.194.174: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=26.119 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 23.781/26.828/34.904/4.114 ms
```

For this particular application, you may also consider using the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to get a high resolution timestamp.

Comment: maybe it is just my server, but after switching to ethernet, the functions ping is significantly higher than https://www.meter.net/ping-test/. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ping uses [RTD/RTT (Round-trip delay/time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay). The **RTD** should be calculated from the time you sent the **request** to the time you receive the **response**.